# What does "a" do at the end of a sql statement?

Tags: sql-server

I have a code here in the screenshot. At the end of the code you see a "a"

When i try to remove the "a" and run the code, it fails but it works with the "a"

what is the significance of this ?
[image]

Comment: by the way i don't believe you are using MySQL the brackets indicate SQL Server (MSSQL)

Comment: @RaymondNijland well well.. I didn't notice that. Nevertheless, explanation should remain same for all major RDBMS

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as properly formatted text, not an image. You're more likely to get an answer if others can copy/paste your text and reproduce the error.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for pointing it out. I am new to this. I changed the tag

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Question was originally tagged MySQL. However, the explanation below should still apply for all the major RDBMS.

It is an Aliasname for the [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). A Derived table is basically a sub-select query. In MySQL, every [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) should have its own Alias, so that outer Select queries can refer to the columns/expressions from the Derived Table. Without a table name/alias, MySQL cannot determine the origin of a column value unambiguously.

From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html):

> The [AS] tbl_name clause is mandatory because every table in a FROM
>   clause must have a name. Any columns in the derived table must have
>   unique names.

Comment: With derived table Madhur means a subquery.. MySQL devs calls a subquery a derived table if those subqueries are in the FROM clause where optimizations happen.. but i don't believe he is using MySQL the brackets in the query indicate SQL Server (MSSQL)

Comment: "is it mandatory to add an alias"  -- No, it's not mandatory but it is considered a best practice.  Just do it.

Comment: @user1443098 In MySQL, it is mandatory; please read the answer (with Doc reference)

Comment: It's mandatory in sql server for derrived tables, but not otherwise @RifadhZizou

Comment: @scsimon correct. it is not mandatory in general but is sometimes when using a derived table (but not always, e.g. when the derived table is the target of an IN or EXISTS condition.)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I think this about SQL Server, at least that's the tag.

Comment: @user1443098 the `IN` clause returns a Boolean type as does exists... the values of the result of IN and EXISTS aren't used anywhere, which is how it's different than a derived table. I don't know what you mean by *it is not mandatory in general but is sometimes*. Derrived tables are result sets... exists and in aren't

Comment: @scsimon exactly.  FWIW if a subquery is the target of IN or EXISTS, it is a derived table.  Just one that doesn't need an alias

Comment: Still confused at your comment @user1443098 but glad you understand i suppose

Comment: @user1443098 Derived tables are special subquery which exists in a `FROM` clause only. Subqueries in `IN` or `EXISTS` are not called Derived Tables. Regarding the SQL server thing; question was retagged later. It was originally MySQL tag. That is why the answer referring MySQL docs.